# shape an Image with border radius

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, tailwind-css

I want to shape an image like this with CSS and Tailwind but I got confused totally. Do you have any idea?

[image]

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question needs improvement. For starters, it's not even clear what's an image in that scenario.

Comment: Don't thank me. Take action to improve your post. It's about to be closed since it doesn't meet site requirements. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think images are transparent and background shapes are generated by CSS ([clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path)).
Like this:

```css
.card{
  width: 420px;
  height: 310px;
  margin: 30px;
  border-radius: 5px 20px 20px 20px;
  background: #00c853;
  position: relative;
}

.card::before{
    content:  '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -18px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #00c853;
    border-radius: 20px 0 0 0;
    clip-path: path('M 0 0 L 160 0 C 185 2, 175 16, 200 18 L 0 50 z');
}
```

```html
<div class='card'></div>
```